# Some information about DOWXV503

Tags: polymers

I want to know about the attractor DOWXV503. Is there any scientific book or article about this material?  Any information is useful and it will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more information about the material ;-) - where did you find the name, give a little context etc - help us help you!

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend.

The material is Dowex V503 a polymeric absorbent for the removal of organics from humid air streams. See more  [here](http://msdssearch.dow.com/PublishedLiteratureDOWCOM/dh_0047/0901b80380047a8f.pdf?filepath=liquidseps/pdfs/noreg/177-01885.pdf&fromPage=GetDoc) and [here](https://water.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/426)